# Get transaction abort error as because of trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a trigger  on the DELTEK.MFG_BOM that looks for an UPDATE or INSERT to that table where the DELETK.MFG_BOM.MODIFIED_BY is not  In ("C10863","M100133","M100196","M100273","M100212”, “DELTEK”)

IF someone other than one of the ID’s above updates or inserts into the table, It will send an email.

When user test it they are getting abortion error. What is the reason for this.

This is my trigger code.

```
USE PRODCP7
GO
Create  TRIGGER DELTEK.MFG_BOM_MODIFIED_BY on DELTEK.MFG_BOM
AFTER INSERT , UPDATE  
AS
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
Begin
    if exists (Select 1  From inserted Where MODIFIED_BY NOT IN ('C10863','M100133','M100196','M100273','M100212', 'DELTEK') )
    Begin

        SELECT Inserted.ASY_PART_ID, Inserted.ASY_PART_RVSN_ID, DELTEK.ITEM.ITEM_DESC, 
        Inserted.MODIFIED_BY, DELTEK.MI_CP_USER_NAME_LOOKUP.NAME, Inserted.TIME_STAMP into #Tmp
        FROM (Inserted 
        LEFT JOIN DELTEK.MI_CP_USER_NAME_LOOKUP ON Inserted.MODIFIED_BY = DELTEK.MI_CP_USER_NAME_LOOKUP.USER_ID) 
        LEFT JOIN DELTEK.ITEM ON Inserted.ASY_PART_KEY = DELTEK.ITEM.ITEM_KEY
        GROUP BY Inserted.ASY_PART_ID, Inserted.ASY_PART_RVSN_ID, DELTEK.ITEM.ITEM_DESC,
        Inserted.MODIFIED_BY, DELTEK.MI_CP_USER_NAME_LOOKUP.NAME, Inserted.TIME_STAMP
        HAVING Inserted.MODIFIED_BY Not In ('C10863','M100133','M100196','M100273','M100212','DELTEK')
        ORDER BY Inserted.ASY_PART_ID, Inserted.MODIFIED_BY;


        SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT ASY_PART_ID AS 'td','', ASY_PART_RVSN_ID AS 'td','', ISNULL(ITEM_DESC,'') AS 'td','', 
        MODIFIED_BY AS 'td','', ISNULL(NAME,'') AS 'td','', TIME_STAMP AS 'td',''
        From #Tmp a 
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

        SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Trigger Report Mail</H3>
        <table border = 1> 
        <tr>
        <th> ASY_PART_ID </th> <th> ASY_PART_RVSN_ID  </th> <th> ITEM_DESC </th>
        <th> MODIFIED_BY </th> <th> NAME </th> <th> TIME_STAMP </th> </tr>'    


        SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'SQL Mail', -- replace with your SQL Database Mail Profile 
        @body = @body,
        @body_format ='HTML',
        @recipients = 'wasay@gmail.com', -- replace with your email address
        @subject = 'Email of Trigger Report on Table : DELTEK.MFG_BOM '  


    End
END
```

Comment: Can you send mail without trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually create a queue to post all the email messages and an SP to send the emails.

See SQL Server Service Broker (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190495.aspx) where the SP that processes the queue is the one sending the emails. This way is more clear and you should be able to debug easier the code.

Btw, in the above code, you don't need to create the #Tmp table. Just append the 1st select on the 2nd query.